# How do I unmask a service in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

I'm running ansible 2.6.2 on my Mac, against a Debian-based Linux system.

There is a service called `hostapd`, which, when you install from the repos, comes pre-masked.

My Ansible playbook installs hostapd, configures it, and needs to unmask, start, and enable it.

In theory, it should just be as simple as:

```
- name: HostAPD | Make sure the service is unmasked, started, and enabled
  systemd:
    name: hostapd
    state: started
    enabled: yes
    masked: no
```

When I run that, I just get a:

```
FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Error loading unit file 'hostapd': org.freedesktop.systemd1.UnitMasked \"Unit hostapd.service is masked.\""}
```

I tried to separate out the tasks, and just run:

```
- name: HostAPD | Make sure the service is unmasked
  systemd:
    name: hostapd
    masked: no
```

But I still get the same error.
For some reason, it's failing to unmask the service because the service is masked... I would have thought that would be a requirement - not a reason to fail.

Am I doing something wrong? I tried adding `daemon_reload: yes` to it as well, but that didn't help.

Comment: You could just use the `command` module to run `systemctl unmask hostapd`.

Comment: The problem with using `command` or `shell` to replace tasks that modules can already do is that a simple command will always show as 'changed' when you run the task. You either need to be ok with that, or write a whole bunch of checks to explain to ansible when a command has changed something, and when it hasn't. In my experience, that usually involves writing additional tasks that check if something needs to be changed or not, quickly growing your playbook

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was a bug in systemd module in Ansible 2.6 and fixed in Ansible 2.7. If possible then upgrade ansible to 2.7 or latest then retry. Otherwise, can use `command` or `shell` module as @larsks suggested.

Comment: I can confirm I cannot reproduce the problem with ansible 2.9.7.

Comment: That explains why I was pretty sure it was working when I wrote the task, but isn''t working now that I was running it months later. I guess I was using a newer version of Ansible when I wrote it. Thanks